# Where is it better to make the redux app logic?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I have an **react-redux** app where a certain **action**-creator exist (function get any title to filter the list of objects):

```
export const filterTests = (title) => dispatch => {
    axios.get(`/api/tests/?title=${title}`)
        .then(res => {
            dispatch({
                type: GET_TESTS,
                payload: res.data
            });
            dispatch({
                type: FILTER_TESTS,
                payload: { title }
            });
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```

And a **reducer**:

```
export default function (state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case GET_TESTS:
            return {
                ...state,
                tests: action.payload,
            };
        case FILTER_TESTS:
            return {
                ...state,
                tests: state.tests.filter((test) => test.title.includes(action.payload.title)),
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

It works, but I think it's better to move the filtering ligic somewhere else (especially if I want to complicate the action):

```
tests: state.tests.filter((test) => test.title.toLowerCase().includes(action.payload.title.toLowerCase()))
```

**Where is it better to transfer this logic?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Redux docs,

Things you should never do inside a **reducer**:

- Mutate its arguments;
- Perform side effects like API calls and routing transitions;
- Call non-pure functions, e.g. Date.now() or Math.random().

As long as your function logic is **pure**, **reducer** is the right place here.

If you are worried about number of lines of code, you can move the logic to a `Utils.js` file with a function name like `filterByTitle(...)`. Then import that function in the reducer and use it as below

```
case FILTER_TESTS:
  return {
    ...state,
    tests: filterByTitle(state.tests, action.payload.title),
  };
```

Comment: It's about filtering an array of data, it's not mutation, so this is pure logic. Thanks for the advice!